# django: Taking user input from form and performing operation based on input

Tags: python, django, forms, user-input

New to Django. I am trying to take user input from a form and perform an operation based on the content of the form. Specifically, comparing the user input (string) with a list.

I have working code to replicate this in a python file, but I am confused how to implement this into django. Note 'userinput' is not actually input from the user. See below:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


userinput = "hello, how are you?"
sCV = userinput.replace(",",'')
cv = nltk.word_tokenize(sCV)

blist = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey']

def words():
    #How many words from input are in the list
    b_words = set(word for word in cv if word in blist)
    print ("Number of similar words: ", len(b_words))
    #What words are missing
    mwords = set(word for word in blist if word not in cv)
    print("Missing words from list are: " , mwords)

words()
```

I don't want to store the the data from the user, so I do not want to retrieve it from a table.

I have a form to take user input:

```
<div class = "container">
<form action="#" method ="post">
  <div>
    <label for="cv">Enter details: </label>
    <textarea name="cv" id='cv' rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="20000"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

In summary:

I want the user to submit a form. When they click submit, it will redirect them to a page that tells them what words they are missing from the list, and how many they have.

I am using django 1.9 and python 3.6.4

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Your form action should have a route for the backend code. In there you can pull the details by doing `details = request.form.get("cv")`.

Comment: is that in the return of the def?

Comment: by def do you mean function? The form action should call a "process" function, in that function you can get the details from the form with `details = request.form.get("cv")`. Then you can `return` whatever view you decide.

Comment: yes the function. Thanks for the assistance. I'll give that a shot.